# <script> tag problem in html file in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Please cosnsider me as beginner. if you think this question is stupid, sorry for that**

1. I added html file in react js as "num.html"
2. In that "num.html", it has  tag.
3. I want to use that html file in my react component. so, i rendered in my app component.
4. it was showing error like :

ERROR in ./src/num.html 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> 

5. I want to use script tag on that html file . but react js not allowing. is there any alternative?

Comment: What's your exact code that is causing the issue? I am not an expert on reactjs, but judging from the error message, the rendering problem is right at the beginning of the file. Maybe the '<script>' isn't the issue at all, but much rather a BOM or something?

Comment: ReactJS in many ways replaces what HTML would do.  This means concepts like importing JavaScript from HTML are a bit backwards in ReactJS as most developers would use ReactJS modules (written in JavaScript).  When you attempt to add an HTML file as a module, it doesn't know what to do with it.   If you prefer to keep your HTML and only import ReactJS features into that page, you may consider this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should have convert your html file to js file. Then you put react js common format. Now you will be able your html code in react component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

react has a file index.html origin, i think u can put your javascript in this file, bellow root element. But I think no one do that. :v

Answer (score -2):

first you should replace .html to .js then type rsc and vs code give stracter then paste the HTML code in react file.